# Complex numbers in

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I'm studing structures, in the fallowing code my teacher created a structure of the complex numbers (numbers that are formed by two parts: a real one and an imaginary one).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#ifndef COMPLEX_DATA_H
#define COMPLEX_DATA_H
struct complex_data 

 {
   double re = 0; // real part
   double im = 0; // immaginary part
 };

#endif

int main()

 {

  std::cout << "Insert two complex numbers (re, im): ";
  complex_data z1, z2;
  std::cin >> z1.re >> z1.im;
  std::cin >> z2.re >> z2.im;

  ... // the code continues

  }
```

I'd like to ask two questions:

1. Leaving z1 and z2 uninitialized will cause any trouble considering they're inside a function and their default inizialitation is undefined?
2. How can we write the actual form of a variable that is a complex number?

   In reality is something like this c = 3 + 2i.

   But if we write it, the computer will sum it because it don't know the difference between real numbers and imaginary ones. So we'll be forced to use a string, but in this case it'll become a sequence of charcaters! Any idea?

   Using Ubuntu 14.04, g++ 4.9.2.

Comment: But the member in the structures *do* have default initialization, just not by a default constructor.

Comment: You should define an operator+. Summing should be done component wise, as summing 2 complex number is done by components.

Comment: those are two very different questions. one question at a time, please.

Comment: And no you can't do `3 + 2i` because then the compiler may use the standard imaginary number type due to the `i` suffix.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I know that they have a defalut initialization, but isn't it undefined? It should lead to errors..

Comment: @Karoly Horvath Okay, choose one of your choice then :)

Comment: If a member is default-initialized like in your structure, then they are initialized. It's well defined behavior. If you declare a local non-static variable of the structure, then both members will be zero.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I still didn't studied what means "static", I'll look for it then If it's necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++11, you have [User defined literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) (and since C++14 you have the standard literal [operator ""i](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i) for the pure imaginary number of `std::complex<double>`).

You may write your own `operator ""_i` for your custom `struct complex_data` and also `operator +` to have what you expect, something like:

```
constexpr complex_data operator"" _i(unsigned long long d)
{ return complex_data{ 0.0, static_cast<double>(d) }; }
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/U6usiI).

Comment: I'll look for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Q1- Constructors are meant to intialize the member variables use them.
Q2- Actual Form can be written using strings its just matter of displaying.
c = 3 + 2i.
Compiler really dont know this, you can overload + operarator.
if you define + operator addition will be performed. (whatever code is written in that function e.g real+= a.real;)